# How to prevent buffer overflow in C/C++?

Tags: c++, redirect, pipe

I am using the following code to redirect stdout to a pipe, then read all the data from the pipe to a buffer. I have 2 problems:

**first problem:** when i send a string (after redirection) bigger then the pipe's BUFF_SIZE, the program stops responding (deadlock or something).

**second problem:** when i try to read from a pipe before something was sent to stdout. I get the same response, the program stops responding - _read command stuck's ...

**The issue is that i don't know the amount of data  that will be sent to the pipe after the redirection.**

The first problem, i don't know how to handle and i'll be glad for help. The second problem i solved by a simple workaround, right after the redirection i print space character to stdout. but i guess that this solution is not the correct one ...

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <iostream>

#define READ 0
#define WRITE 1
#define BUFF_SIZE 5

using namespace std;

int main()
{

  int stdout_pipe[2];
  int saved_stdout;

  saved_stdout = _dup(_fileno(stdout));            // save stdout 

  if(_pipe(stdout_pipe,BUFF_SIZE, O_TEXT) != 0 )   // make a pipe
  {    
    exit(1);
  }

  fflush( stdout );

  if(_dup2(stdout_pipe[1], _fileno(stdout)) != 0 ) //redirect stdout to the pipe 
  { 
    exit(1);
  }

  ios::sync_with_stdio();    
  setvbuf( stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

  //anything sent to stdout goes now to the pipe
  //printf(" ");//workaround for the second problem

  printf("123456");//first problem

  char buffer[BUFF_SIZE] = {0};
  int nOutRead = 0;
  nOutRead = _read(stdout_pipe[READ], buffer, BUFF_SIZE); //second problem
  buffer[nOutRead] = '\0';

  // reconnect stdout

  if (_dup2(saved_stdout, _fileno(stdout)) != 0 ) 
  {        
         exit(1);
  }
  ios::sync_with_stdio();

  printf("buffer: %s\n", buffer);
  }
```

Comment: Why is your buffer size so small?

Comment: To avoid buffer overflow, don't write over the end of the buffer.

Comment: the buffer is small only for this example ... i use a big buffer but i am looking for a technique to have an average buffer and in need (when it is overflowed) to make it bigger ...

Comment: "don't write over the end of the buffer" - how do i do that?
in my code , after the redirection i call for a function which makes calculations and prints to stdout. I dont have the functions code ...

Comment: You're writing past the end of the array here: `buffer[nOutRead] = '\0';`   Change the length passed to `_read` to BUFF_SIZE - 1 to avoid that when `_read` actually fills the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using blocking I/O calls, while both ends of the pipe are connected to the same process. If you don't know how much data there will be, this is just a deadlock situation waiting to happen.

`printf` is a blocking call, which means that it will not return until all data has been written to the output device (the pipe in this case), or until a write error is signalled (for example, the other end of the pipe is closed).
`_read` works similarly. It only returns when it has a full buffer worth of data or it knows that the end of the input has been reached (which can be signalled by closing the write-end of the pipe).

The only ways around this are

- to use non-blocking I/O (which is not feasible if you don't have access to the code that calls `printf`), or
- to ensure the reading and writing happens in different processes or threads, or
- to use a temporary file for buffering, instead of the buffer of a pipe.

Comment: i think i understand, in my case, using a file for buffering is the solution, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pipes are unidirectional. Ie. you can either write to a pipe (x)or you can read from it.

To simulate a pipeline, try the following (the below is C, not C++):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc)
{
    int pfds[2];

    pipe(pfds);

    if (!fork()) {
        close(1);       /* close stdout, check for errors */
        dup(pfds[1]);   /* make stdout same as pfds[1], dup reuses lowest fd */
        close(pfds[0]); /* not needed */
        execlp("ls", "ls", NULL); /* or write() in whatever way you want */
    } else {
        close(0);       /* close stdin, check for errors please! */
        dup(pfds[0]);   /* make stdin same as pfds[0] */
        close(pfds[1]); /* not needed on this end */
        execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL); /* or read() */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[edit] By the way, your code does not overflow a buffer. Its only relation to buffer overflow is that you're reading into a statically allocated array...if you `read()` more than `sizeof buffer` elements, then you'll run into problems.

Comment: i've forgot to post that I want my code to run under one process ... but i think i've understood the problem and the solution ... thanks

Comment: No matter, if you want bidirectional communication, you should use two pipes..that's the gist of it. GL. :)

Answer (score 0):

You must use non-blocking I/O if you don't want read or write to be blocked in this case.

Comment: what do you mean? as i written in the previous comment : in my code , after the redirection i call for a function which makes calculations and prints to stdout. I dont have access to the functions code